# error parallel distribution in omnet++

Tags: parallel-processing, omnet++

When I try to make parallel distribution in ubuntu14.04 
I got this error: Cannot append hostname to file name `results/General-0.elog`:no HOST , HOSTNAME or COMPUTERNAME (Windows) environment variable.

```
[General]
network = Network
parallel-simulation = true
parsim-communications-class = "cMPICommunications"
parsim-synchronization-class = "cNullMessageProtocol"
**.scalar-recording = false
**.vector-recording = false
*.GCN.**.partition-id =0
*.lcn[*].partition-id =1
*.sn[*].partition-id =2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `HOST` environment variable.
Type in console where you start `OMNeT++`:

```
export HOST=host01
```

or in IDE go to `Run` | `Run Configurations` | your configuration | `Environment` and add a new `HOST` variable with `host01` value.

Comment: I tried it but it is terminated. And shows Starting...
$ cd /home/cea/Desktop/simulation/wsnfuture
$ wsnfuture -r 0 omnetpp.ini

Setting up Tkenv...
Simulation terminated with exit code: 1
Working directory: /home/cea/Desktop/simulation/wsnfuture
Command line: wsnfuture -r 0 omnetpp.ini
Environment variables: PATH=/home/cea/omnetpp-4.6/bin::/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/cea/omnetpp-4.6/bin LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/cea/omnetpp-4.6/lib:: OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=/home/cea/omnetpp-4.6/images

Comment: Try to run your simulation in IDE in debug mode to determine where is the source of termination.

Comment: I tried in debug mode and it says:  Error in module (cModule) Network (id=1) during network setup: wrong partitioning: value 2 too large for 'Network.GCN' (total partitions=1) (**I have 1 gcn,36 lcn and 250 sn in my network.Lcns are connected their neighbor lcn.Also lcn number 14 15 20 and 21 connected to the Gcn.Sensors are uniformly distributed).Isn't possible to make parallel distribution in this case.